# Sometimes this happens Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification

Tags: android

So, my app always work perfectly, but sometimes show this error
Bad notification posted from package com.myapp: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification

```
    Intent intentRadar = new Intent(this, RadarActivity.class);
    intentRadar.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int)System.currentTimeMillis(), intentRadar, 0);

    //Intent to close app
    Intent intentClose = new Intent(this, CloseAppReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent closeIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intentClose,0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setTicker(getResources().getString(R.string.titulo_app_executando));
    builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.titulo_app_executando));
    builder.setContentText(getString(R.string.msg_app_run));
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);//Seta a intent do radar para voltar
    builder.setOngoing(true);

    //action off app
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.turn_off, getResources().getString(R.string.off_app), closeIntent);
    builder.setWhen(0);
    builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);

    notificationAppRun = builder.build();

    nm.notify(R.drawable.ic_notification,notificationAppRun);//show notification
```

Comment: I bumped into the same problem. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you use remoteView?

```
nm.notify(R.drawable.ic_notification, notificationAppRun); //show notification
```

I think the first param is wrong. You need to set an id here, not the drawable id